# Bogoliubov-Valatin transformation generalisation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, quantum-spin, spin-models

Considering the following Heisenberg Hamiltonian (with spin $S$ , and $J<0$ for the case of an antiferromagnet) when we only consider interactions between first neighbors in a square lattice in the presence of a field $B$:

$$ H = J \sum_{\left\langle ij\right\rangle} \mathbf{S}_i \cdot \mathbf{S}_j - B \sum_{i} S_i^z $$

how can we generalise the Bogoliubov-Valatin transformation:

$$ \varepsilon_0 \left( \hat{a}^{\dagger} \hat{a} + \hat{b}^{\dagger} \hat{b} \right) + \Delta \hat{a}^{\dagger} \hat{b}^{\dagger} + \Delta^* \hat{a}\hat{b}  = - \varepsilon_0 + E (1+ \hat{\alpha}^{\dagger} \hat{\alpha} + \hat{\beta}^{\dagger} \hat{\beta}) $$

where:

$$ E = \sqrt{ \varepsilon_0^2 - |\Delta|^2}$$

in such a way that allows us to show that the Neel phase, with the magnetization of the sub-lattice pointing along $\hat{z}$, is unstable for all values $B \neq 0$?

Comment: I do not quite understand your questions. If you want to get the spin wave solution on the Neel phase, you could use Holstein-Primakoff transformation to get a boson model then  diagonalize it.

Comment: Probably a typo, but as the Hamiltonian is written $J<0$ would favor ferromagnetism, not antiferromagnetism. Anyway, as the previous commenter suggests, your jump from spin Hamiltonian to some $\hat{a}$,$\hat{b}$ operators is quite abrupt. If these are intended to be two species of Holstein-Primakoff bosons you really need to set up the spin-wave problem first. That'll likely help.